# API Gateway and ALB in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, api-gateway

I need help with this situation...
I have a k8s cluster where I have deployed three services (configured as ClusterIP type)
I have created an AWS Ingress that provision an ALB. The ALB has an AWS issued certificate for the domain *.example.co.uk.
I configured the ingress with hosted based rules:

```
  rules:
  - host: service1.example.co.uk
    http: 
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: service1
            port:
              name: https
  - host: service2.example.co.uk
    http: 
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: service2
            port:
              name: https
  - host: service3.example.co.uk
    http: 
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: service3
            port:
              name: https
```

The ALB is internet facing so it has its own dns name.
If I configure DNS CNames in Cloudflare for the different hosts all works fine.

I want to put an API Gateway in front of the ALB.
I created the API Gateway for a REST API with HTTP integration.
In the Endpoint URL i put the ALB dns address.
I get an error that says:

Execution failed due to configuration error: Host name '<<ALB_address>>.elb.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com' does not match the certificate subject provided by the peer (CN=*.example.co.uk)

I also tried with

- a NLB in front of the ALB, but same error.
- create custom domain

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

EDIT:
Here some screenshoot to show my setup, from the top
1- API Gateway integration request
2- Custom Domain Mapping
3- Error Message
4- Cloudwatch log of the error

[image: Screenshot of my setup]

The Certificate is AWS Issued and is the same used by the ALB and Custom Domain.

Answer (score 0):

If you are putting an API gateway in front of ALB, you need to create a [custom domain name](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-custom-domains.html) for your API.  (Assuming you want to enable https, you should also load your [domain certificate](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-custom-domains-prerequisites.html) into AWS ACM.)

CloudFlare CNAME record should then point to the Custom Domain Endpoint, not the Invoke URL of your API stage -- and most definitely not to the ALB URL.  The ALB will be called by the API gateway.

Comment: I already have done that but I get the Host name '<<ALB_address>>.elb.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com' does not match the certificate subject provided by the peer (CN=*.example.co.uk)

Comment: Which service / command gives this error?

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for your answer, I have edited my question with some screenshoot of the API Gateway setup and the error log.
The ALB redirect to three services, two of which are REST APIs one is a php app. I want to create API Gateways for the two REST APIs. The screenshoots are for the API Gateway of one API in particular to retrieve the swagger.json
Hope that make sense

Comment: Your phrase "I want to put an API Gateway in front of the ALB" threw me off.  An architectural diagram would help.  So you have browser -> ALB -> API?  In that case you need to attach the SSL cert to ALB, not API Gw: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/associate-acm-certificate-alb-nlb/

Comment: Sorry if I didn't use the right terminology (still learning), basically I want all the request to the APIs (services deployed in K8s) to be handles by the API Gateway, so
it should Browser -> API Gateway -> ALB -> APIs (k8s service)
(If that make sense)

Comment: In that case, your first API gateway will do SSL termination, and all internal requests can be just http (unless you want to have an SSL back-end call too, which will be a more complex, but possible, solution.)  So you should attach the ACM SSL cert to your first API Gw and point CloudFlare DNS record to the custom domain endpoint of that first API Gw.  What error are you getting when you do it?

Comment: Thanks Alex for your reply.
Yes, that's my problem I need to have SSL on the back-end too.
Should I use a client certificate for that?
I made some progress (it all works) by using http proxy method (by defining a {proxy+} resource), changing the rules of the ALD from host-based to path based and using http call to the ALB, but if I put as endpoint https://<ALB_Address> , I've got the above error?

Comment: Haven't done it myself, but saw a manual on how to set up the back-end SSL: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started-client-side-ssl-authentication.html

Comment: API Gateway returns "Internal server error" for any exception: it is not intended to be informative to prevent differential attack.  Look at the CloudWatch logs for more detailed debugging.